# Bash function works but will not accept autocomplete

Tags: bash

I've written a couple functions in my .bashrc to make navigating easier in bash:

```
# makes 'cs' cd and ll
function cs () {
    cd "$1" && ll
    }

# makes 'cv' cd and vim
function cv () {
    mkdir -p $(dirname "$1") &&
    cd $(dirname "$1") &&
    if [ $(basename "$1") == no ]
    then
        :
    else
        vim $(basename "$1")
    fi
    }

# makes cc a 'smart' cd
function cc () {
    if [[ "$1" == */ ]]
    then
    cs "$1"
    else
    cv "$1"
    fi
    }
```

The first two work as expected: `cs` moves and lists and `cv` moves and opens in vim (or creates the path to file). `cc` also works, but when I try to use tab autocompletion with it, my shell freezes. Even a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> won't unfreeze it.

Any ideas about why it won't autocomplete?

Thanks.

Comment: First you may also try CTRL+D (end-of-file signal), second you may try to run it with "bash -x" for debug info.. + can you please provide input example ?

Comment: @nabeel Thanks. I think you might be mistaking this as a bash script. It's just in my ~/.bashrc. I've edited the above to reflect this.

Comment: `cc` hasn't even run yet when you try to use tab completion on its argument. You have some other problem. That said, `[[ -d $1 ]]` is a much better way to determine if the argument is a directory name.